# Смена коллекций данных в одном datagrid при выборе в combobox WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

У меня есть 2 коллекции с разными данными

Модель первой коллекции:

```
 public partial class DistrictPoint
    {
        public int IdDisctrictPoint { get; set; }
        public int IdDistrict { get; set; }
        public double? DisctrictPointX { get; set; }
        public double? DisctrictPointY { get; set; }
        public double? DisctrictPointZ { get; set; }
    }
```

Модель второй коллекции:

```
internal class AngularMeasure
    {
        private int _id;
        public int ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        private string _longitude;
        public string Longitude
        {
            get { return _longitude; }
            set { _longitude = value; }
        }

        private string _width;
        
        public string Width
        {
            get { return _width; }
            set { _width = value; }
        }

        private double? _pointZ;
        public double? PointZ
        {
            get { return _pointZ; }
            set { _pointZ = value; }

        }
    }
```

Как мне сделать так, что бы если пользователь при выборе допустим в combobox элемента, то подгружалась в один тот же DataGrid та или иная коллекция данных?

Comment: В datagrid заранее определенно кол-во столбцов. Кол-во столбцов = кол-ву отображаемых свойств из модели. Если у вас в моделях разное кол-во свойство, то какое-то свойств вы не сможете отобразить в daragrid. На сколько мне известно, нельзя динамически при изменении значения combox - менять кол-во столбцов в datagrid

Comment: @alex6327 Спасибо, могли бы вынести это в ответ, что бы я его отметил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В datagrid заранее определенно кол-во столбцов. Кол-во столбцов = кол-ву отображаемых свойств из модели. Если у вас в моделях разное кол-во свойств, то какое-то свойств вы не сможете отобразить в daragrid. На сколько мне известно, нельзя динамически при изменении значения combox - менять кол-во столбцов в datagrid